# Working with multiple grouped lines in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have following lines of data; pipe ('|') delimited CSV data:

```
id|name|address|updated_date
1|Binita|Satdobato|20151212
1|Binita|Kalimati|20161212
2|Rohita|Kalanki|20151212
2|Rohita|Dharan|20141212
```

Now i need to group by id and name, and update address with the latest updated_date. Following is the expected output:

```
id|name|address|updated_date
1|Binita|Kalimati|20151212
1|Binita|Kalimati|20161212
2|Rohita|Kalanki|20151212
2|Rohita|Kalanki|20141212
```

Now how can i achieve the output by using Spark in JavaRDD.

Comment: Have you tried something?